# Looping into all websites, PowerShell error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: powershell

I have some powershell script which is looping into all websites in a webapplication. I have full control permissions in the policy in Central Admin. In this powershell loop I got this error at some sites:

> PowerShell and Sharepoint: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.

I think this error occurred because I don't have permissions at some websites. But I would like to skip sites which throw these errors. How can I do that? This is my script:

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) { 
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" 
} 

$webApp = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication]::Lookup("http://portal.myCompany.net") 

foreach ($site in $webApp.Sites) 
{ 
     foreach($webSite in $site.AllWebs)
     {
       # some logic
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to open the PowerShell with **Run with Administrator** previlages.

The following code worked fine for me,

*param($Site,$FilePath)

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

function GenerateAllSitecollectionsInWebapplication ($url)
{
    write-host "Sitecollection List Extraction started...." -foregroundcolor red
    try
      {
         $Site=Get-SPSite $url         
         $spWebApp = $Site.WebApplication
         $TotalList = @()
          write-host "Below is the list of all sitecollections for webapplication" + $spWebApp + "..." -foregroundcolor red 
         foreach($allsites in $spWebApp.Sites)
         {
           $list =  $allsites.url 
           write-host $list -foregroundcolor blue        
         }                       
      }
   catch
      {
          write-host "Unable to Extract Sitecollection List..." -foregroundcolor red
          break
      }
} 

GenerateAllSitecollectionsInWebapplication  -Url "www.yoururl.com/"*
```

Comment: this script is working, but this is not what I am asking. I would loop into each site collection into all websites. There are some websites where I dont have permissions and got an error. these websites I would like to skip and go to the next website.

Answer (score 0):

Use following to only get sub sites where user has permissions:

```
$webCollection = web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser()
```

Comment: where do I need to use "web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser()"? Do I need to replace it for $site.AllWebs?

Comment: $web = $site.OpenWeb()  foreach ($subweb in $Web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser())

Comment: you are expecting that I have permissions on all sitecollections. But thats not true. there are some site collections where I dont have permissions and then I got this exception, and the script looping is stopping.